# Angular js unit test mock document

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, angularjs, testing, document

I am trying to test angular service which does some manipulations to DOM via `$document` service with jasmine. 
Let's say it simply appends some directive to the `<body>` element.

Such service could look like

```
(function(module) {
    module.service('myService', [
        '$document',
        function($document) {
            this.doTheJob = function() {
                $document.find('body').append('<my-directive></my directive>');
            };
        }
    ]);
})(angular.module('my-app'));
```

And I want to test it like this

```
describe('Sample test' function() {
    var myService;

    var mockDoc;

    beforeEach(function() {
        module('my-app');

        // Initialize mock somehow. Below won't work indeed, it just shows the intent
        mockDoc = angular.element('<html><head></head><body></body></html>');

        module(function($provide) {
            $provide.value('$document', mockDoc);
        });
    });

    beforeEach(inject(function(_myService_) {
        myService = _myService_;
    }));

    it('should append my-directive to body element', function() {
        myService.doTheJob();
        // Check mock's body to contain target directive
        expect(mockDoc.find('body').html()).toContain('<my-directive></my-directive>');
    });
});
```

So the question is what would be the best way to create such mock?

Testing with real `document` will give us much trouble cleaning up after each test and does not look like a way to go with.

I've also tried to create a new real document instance before each test, yet ended up with different failures.

Creating an object like below and checking `whatever` variable works but looks very ugly

```
var whatever = [];
var fakeDoc = {
    find: function(tag) {
              if (tag == 'body') {
                  return function() {
                      var self = this;
                      this.append = function(content) {
                          whatever.add(content);
                          return self;
                      };
                  };
              } 
          }
}
```

I feel that I'm missing something important here and doing something very wrong.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You don't need to mock the `$document` service in such a case. It's easier just to use its actual implementation:

```
describe('Sample test', function() {
    var myService;
    var $document;

    beforeEach(function() {
        module('plunker');
    });

    beforeEach(inject(function(_myService_, _$document_) {
        myService = _myService_;
        $document = _$document_;
    }));

    it('should append my-directive to body element', function() {
        myService.doTheJob();
        expect($document.find('body').html()).toContain('<my-directive></my-directive>');
    });
});
```

Plunker [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/XFxAgyptiH1a9vUoOusm?p=preview).

If you really need to mock it out, then I guess you'll have to do it the way you did:

```
$documentMock = { ... }
```

But that can break other things that rely on the `$document` service itself (such a directive that uses `createElement`, for instance).

<s>**UPDATE**</s>

If you need to restore the document back to a consistent state after each test, you can do something along these lines:

```
afterEach(function() {
    $document.find('body').html(''); // or $document.find('body').empty()
                                     // if jQuery is available
});
```

Plunker [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/kTe4jKUnypfe6SbDECHi?p=preview) (I had to use another container otherwise Jasmine results wouldn't be rendered).

As @AlexanderNyrkov pointed out in the comments, both Jasmine and Karma have their own stuff inside the `body` tag, and wiping them out by emptying the document body doesn't seem like a good idea.

**UPDATE 2**

I've managed to partially mock the `$document` service so you can use the actual page document and restore everything to a valid state:

```
beforeEach(function() {
    module('plunker');

    $document = angular.element(document); // This is exactly what Angular does
    $document.find('body').append('<content></content>');

    var originalFind = $document.find;
    $document.find = function(selector) {
      if (selector === 'body') {
        return originalFind.call($document, 'body').find('content');
      } else {
        return originalFind.call($document, selector);
      }
    }

    module(function($provide) {
      $provide.value('$document', $document);
    });        
});

afterEach(function() {
    $document.find('body').html('');
});
```

Plunker [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/BcGEL8RLsCSJ9Snr7PiG?p=preview).

The idea is to replace the `body` tag with a new one that your SUT can freely manipulate and your test can safely clear at the end of every spec.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.

Such approach will create dependencies between tests. Let's say our service adds something to the `document` with each call to `doTheJob` and then removes added element with calls to `cleanup` method. If some cleanup fails all other tests dependent on the document content may fail.

It's probably possible to restore the original state of document after each test but this can be just as tricky as the original issue.

Comment: @AlexanderNyrkov Assuming that your tests will add things to the document `body`, it's easy to restore everything back to a pristine state by doing `$document.find('body').html('')` (or `$document.find('body').empty()`, if jQuery is available) within an `afterEach` block. I'll update the answer in order to illustrate that.

Comment: I thought about such approach either but karma and jasmine have their stuff inside `body` tag. So emptying the `body` does not look like a good idea for me. We could probably restore it's original state after the test but I'd rather not interfere with test frameworks' stuff

Comment: @AlexanderNyrkov That's odd. I had tested it with one of my test suites (which uses both Jasmine and Karma) before I answered your first comment, and everything worked just fine. :\ Will check it out again to be sure.

Comment: @AlexanderNyrkov I think I got it. In fact Karma puts his stuff inside the `body` tag, as you have said, but it's just `<script>` tags with all it needs to work. Since those scripts had already been loaded when the first test ran, removing them from the `body` doesn't seem to affect the remaining tests. But I agree with you that it doesn't sound a good idea to mess with things that don't belong to you.

Comment: @AlexanderNyrkov I figured out a way to "mock" the `body` tag so you can use the actual `document` and safely perform some cleanup at the end of every test. I'll update the answer with this new code. Hope it helps.

Comment: This is a nice idea, I was thinking about something like this but the exact implementation didn't come to my mind. It still may be better to use straightforward cleanup functions for simple cases but this seems to be the best solution so far and can help a lot for testing tricky stuff. Marking this as an answer. Thank you Michael

Answer (score 6):

You can create an empty test document using [`DOMImplementation#createHTMLDocument()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMImplementation.createHTMLDocument):

```js
describe('myService', function() {
  var $body;

  beforeEach(function() {
    var doc;

    // Create an empty test document based on the current document.
    doc = document.implementation.createHTMLDocument();

    // Save a reference to the test document's body, for asserting
    // changes to it in our tests.
    $body = $(doc.body);

    // Load our app module and a custom, anonymous module.
    module('myApp', function($provide) {
      // Declare that this anonymous module provides a service
      // called $document that will supersede the built-in $document
      // service, injecting our empty test document instead.
      $provide.value('$document', $(doc));
    });

    // ...
  });

  // ...
});
```

Because you're creating a new, empty document for each test, you won't interfere with the page running your tests and you won't have to explicitly clean up after your service between tests.