# Should I append the original or compiled/linked element to body when testing?

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, karma-runner, jasmine-jquery

When I set up tests using just compile and link, the directive is triggered but the element only exists in limbo because the tests below fail if I do not explicitly add it to the DOM.

I am simply wondering whether I should be adding the precompiled `angular.element(...)` to the DOM or the compiled/linked `linkFr(scope)` or if I am going about this all wrong.

## Test Setup

```
beforeEach(inject(function ($rootScope, $compile) {

    var linkFn, el;

    rootScope = $rootScope;

    scope = $rootScope.$new();

    el = angular.element('\
        <a id="testClickConfirm" href="" ng-click="deleteFn()" click-confirm="Test confirmation message">Delete</a>\
    ');

    // $('body').append(el);

    // The $compile method returns the directive's link function
    linkFn = $compile(el);

    // The link function returns the resulting DOM object
    element = linkFn(scope);

    $('body').append(element);

}));
```

## Tests

As long as I call either `$('body').append(el);` or `$('body').append(element);` all tests pass, otherwise they all fail.

```
it('should be added to dom',function(){

    expect(element).toExist();
    expect(element).toBeInDOM();
    expect(element).toBeVisible();

    expect(el).toExist();
    expect(el).toBeInDOM();
    expect(el).toBeVisible();

    expect($('#testClickConfirm')).toExist();
    expect($('#testClickConfirm')).toBeInDOM();
    expect($('#testClickConfirm')).toBeVisible();

}));
```

Comment: Could you provide a Plunker script?

Comment: @MichaelBenford All of the code is here and works. This is just a question of which method is correct, if they are the same, or if another method is better.

Comment: I asked for a script because at first I didn't recognize `toExist()`, `toBeInDOM()` and `toBeVisible()` calls and thought they were pseudocode. But after a quick Google search I found out they are real functions (and very useful, btw). :)

Comment: Ah yes, they are very useful. I used all 3 just to cover all the bases, though I doubt they are all even necessary. I know each has its own limitations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge you only need to append the element to the DOM when your test relies on the browser to compute something (e.g. the size of an element). If that's not required then you can leave it in "limbo".

In the cases you need the element to be inside the DOM, using the compiled version will mostly suffice. I can't think of any scenario where appending the "raw" element to the DOM before compiling it would be useful.

Comment: OK thanks. I did have an issue with this method though because it seems that it will not get cleaned up after each test. Do I have to do this manually?

Comment: Also what about using jasmine-jquery `setFixtures()`. Will that do auto cleanup?

Comment: @ogc-nick What I usually do in such cases is to mock the body tag out so I can clean it up automatically after each test with no effort. Take a look at this [another answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20313575/angular-js-unit-test-mock-document/20366087#20366087) of mine for more details.