# Testing code that uses document.body.querySelectorAll

Tags: angularjs

Trying to test a directive that does the following:

```
var inputs = angular.element(document.body.querySelectorAll('input[ng-model]', elem));
// [code relying on found elements]
```

Running inside karma/jasmine/phantomjs, this fails because it seems that `document` returns the document that contains the test, rather than the compiled template. Is there some way to mock this functionality so it works as expected (for my use case) or some other way to query for those elements?

PS: The elements that need to be located are in no known relation to the element that the directive is applied to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `$document` instead of `document` then mock it in your tests.
See [Angular js unit test mock document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20313575/angular-js-unit-test-mock-document) to learn how to mock `$document`.

Comment: Worked, thanks. The solution that worked was the one by Ian http://stackoverflow.com/a/27409238/907512

Answer (score 0):

The last update in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20366087/4031815) did the trick for me he basically is using the $document service, which is like a wrapper over jQuery and then you can append elements to the body directly and test them:

I'll quote his answer:

> **UPDATE 2**
>
> I've managed to partially mock the `$document` service so you can use
>   the actual page document and restore everything to a valid state:
>
> ```
> beforeEach(function() {
>     module('plunker');
>
>     $document = angular.element(document); // This is exactly what Angular does
>     $document.find('body').append('<content></content>');
>
>     var originalFind = $document.find;
>     $document.find = function(selector) {
>       if (selector === 'body') {
>         return originalFind.call($document, 'body').find('content');
>       } else {
>         return originalFind.call($document, selector);
>       }
>     }
>
>     module(function($provide) {
>       $provide.value('$document', $document);
>     });        
> });
>
> afterEach(function() {
>     $document.find('body').html('');
> });
> ```
>
> Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/kTe4jKUnypfe6SbDECHi?p=preview
>
> The idea is to replace the `body` tag with a new one that your SUT can
>   freely manipulate and your test can safely clear at the end of every
>   spec.